# My synchronous call to d3.json resolves too late

Tags: asynchronous, d3.js

I have a d3.js org chart tree that works just fine if the JSON data is completely embedded in the source code.  However, if I remove the JSON data to an external file and use the below code it fails:

```
<script>
  "use strict";
  var path;

  var treeData;
  async function getjson() {
     treeData = await d3.json("orgchart_ext.json");
    console.log('getjson being called');
  }
  getjson(); 

  console.log('after json');
```

The JS console shows that the after json appears before the getjson being called.  As you can see, I am using an async function but inside using the await option.

How can I redo this code such that code after the getjson function does not run until that function is complete?

A very simple working (json data embedded) can be see here:  https://codepen.io/tbellmer/pen/RwaGXgq

I have been struggling with this for months so any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, I guess that's the expected behavior in an *async* workflow.

If you want your `console.log('after json')` statement to be executed after the `getjson` returns, you need to explicitely `await` it.

It can be done by wrapping your code in an `async` function like so:

```
var path;
var treeData;

async function getjson() {
  treeData = await d3.json("orgchart_ext.json");
  console.log('getjson being called');
}

async function main() {
  await getjson();
  console.log('after json');
}

main();
```

Now your code is waiting for the `getjson` function to be completed before executing the next statement.

Comment: Notice all the interactivity that I have via the other functions.  Will they all continue to work if they are wrapped inside ?

Comment: Yes they should if you call them inside the main() function, in the expected order, etc. But I guess my answer and @steven answer are both valid (ie. solves the problem described which is about "awaiting" and execution order), after which it really depends on how you want to design/organize your code.

Comment: So this kinda works but not completely.  I did as suggested and placed my existing code, functions and all inside a draw function.  This draws out a treeview that emulates an orgchart.  In HTML I have a button to expand or contract all nodes of the treeview.  That call does not work, I get Uncaught ReferenceError: expandAll is not defined.  I tried to move that call outside the draw() method but did not work eihter.  Any ideas - so close...

Answer (score 0):

You could put all your code that draws the chart inside a function. i.e. `draw()`. Then inside your `getjson()` function, call `draw()` after the await.

```js
async function getjson() {
  treeData = await d3.json("orgchart_ext.json");
  draw();
}
```